# Roland R-26 to use for sound design

Tags: portable-recorder

I am thinking about upgrading my PCM-M10 into a X/Y, A/B portable recorder and through my research it seems that the R-26 is a good option.

Do you guys have experience with it? How is the noisefloor of the builtin´s and externalpres?
Does it hold the same quality as the PCM-M10?

Thank you for being a good community :).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have one, but have heard good things. Of interest regarding the mic pre's:

http://www.avisoft.com/recordertests.htm

I'd like to hear a recording comparison with internal mics though too. Wondering how this compares to the pcm-d50 and ls-100 in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

I own a R26 and have a spare M10 at work. 
R26 preamps are pretty decent, but the digital control of the preamps suck, so certain settings are a lot noisier than others.
The built in mics are very noisy and can't be compared to the M10 mics. M10 internal mics are a lot better than the R26. The xy mics are quite noisy but the sound is decent and the stereo width is pretty good. Not useful for ambiances but for recording loud sounds where noise isn't an issue it can work ok. 
I like my R26 but knowing what I know today I would have bought another m10 or saved some money until I could afford at least a tascam 680 (for multiple channels).
Buy some external mics to go with the M10 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wait until the Sony PCM-D100 comes out early next year.
Definitly one i'd buy if I didn't already have a D50.

http://www.soundonsound.com/news?NewsID=16605

Comment: Looks nice, but expensive.. I wonder why they don't release one with XLR inputs? A D50 which had 2 XLR ins and could record them all 4-track would get my money, for sure.

Comment: I've always said that a handheld recorder should be just that, a handheld recorder. This is why I dislike the H4N, it does too much and not very well. 
The Sony recorders are incredibly well built and do exactly what they are built to do.

Comment: agreed, but when you need to pay this much money for a pcmd100 it should be more than a 2track recorder in my opinion. recorder the line inputs and using the built in's at the same time would make it much more interesting.

Comment: edit: 'recorder the line inputs' should be 'recording the line inputs'

Answer (score 0):

I also tried before, and the limiter is very noise. You could find bettet stuff for this price, ZoomH6n.

Comment: what do you mean with "the limiter is very noisy"? why is the zoom h6n better?

Comment: if u see the specifications u find the answer for why zoom could be better.
the noisi limiter does it mean what it mean. it give some noise to the record. its the same noise limiter like earlyer roland stuff have. cheap.

Comment: i'm sorry to disagree, specifications are not always a guarantee for proper functioning or sound, in my opinion. digital limiters in my experience are not specifically noisy, misusage of the function is. i'm not saying that you do that, btw.

Comment: I 100% agree with @Arnoud - there should be nearly zero reason to be hitting the limiters if you gain stage properly (except for very loud fast transients, if so desired for the crunched sound, like a gunshot).

Comment: actually for sound design, yes, u don't need to use a limiter if u record smartly, but if i planning buy a recorder, i like to know i could use all the features properly, maybe if i have to go out to record a dialog for production sound (for that u need definitely limiter).

Comment: limiters are only useful as 'a last resort' in my opinion, when unscripted things happen like improvising actors screaming or shouting. as a seasoned boom operator or recordist you should be able to handle those situations without hitting the limiters. i don't think any dialogue editor will be very happy with a brickwall limited take on his tracks.